# How react native VirtualizedList/FlatList understand that element should be rendered or no?

Tags: react-native

How react native VirtualizedList/FlatList understand that element should be rendered or no?
I'm just wondering if it repels from the viewport or does it contain some other tricky algorithm?

Comment: you could check [the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/621969b8d85d10f4f9b66be7d5deae58651dc6aa/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js)

Comment: You should start from this:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor